# Clarity of Electorate badge description

Tags: discussion, support, badges

[image: Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions]

Wouldn't this read better if it said:

**Voted 600 times** and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Instead of:

Voted on 600 **questions** and 25% or more of total votes are on **questions**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as this would change the meaning. The badge requires **600 votes on questions**, your suggestion requires **600 votes on anything**.

---

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399):

> #### Electorate
>
> - gold; awarded once; same family as Civic Duty (silver)
> - Vote on 600 questions, and have at least 25% of the total number of votes cast be votes on questions
>
>   - Comment votes do not count
>
> This seems to be an especially confusing badge, so here are some examples to address cases commonly complained about on MSO. `Total` is just the total number of votes cast (`Questions` + `Answers`) and `Ratio` is the total number of votes cast that are on questions.
>
> ```
> ┌───────────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────────┐  
> │ Questions │ Answers │ Total │ Ratio │ Electorate awarded? │  
> ├───────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤  
> │       600 │    2400 │  3000 │   20% │   No; ratio too low │  
> │       201 │     401 │   602 │  ~33% │ No; < 600 questions │  
> │       599 │       0 │   599 │  100% │ No; < 600 questions │  
> │       600 │       0 │   600 │  100% │                 Yes │  
> │       500 │     500 │  1000 │   50% │ No; < 600 questions │  
> │       650 │     650 │  1300 │   50% │                 Yes │  
> └───────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
> ```

Comment: Ah, I was deciphering the meaning from the wrong direction. Thanks for clarifying.